# Handling generated files in a Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio Project that is using a MSBuild task to generate some code files. (The basis are xml files, and the generated code is quite lengthy, but noting special, just a lot of boilerplate.)

I’m not sure how I should handle the generated files:

- Not include generated files in the project, and use MSBuild to make sure they get compiled (by adding respective `<Compile...>` tags to the `<Target>`).
- Include generated files in the project, but [exclude them from source control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192113/do-i-check-generated-code-in-to-source-control-or-not).

Any other options? Are there issues with these options? Experiences so far? Recommendations or best practices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Part of Your Project Should be in Source Code Control?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120477/what-part-of-your-project-should-be-in-source-code-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I include only the source files WRT source control. Its a rare case when generated files should be added to source control - maybe if they were generated once and never changed, and the generation step is lengthy or complex, otherwise I can't think of a good reason.

For compilation - if they need to be added to the project then I tend to add them - I prefer not to have hidden compilation files as part of the project as I prefer to know what its really building without any surprises. I do tend to put generated files in a filtered folder though so they are tucked away from daily view though.

Comment: I think that “not to have hidden compilation files as part of the project” is a good argument.