# Identify downsides: versioning auto-generated Terraform source code

Tags: versioning, templates, code-generation

**HINT:** the purpose of this question is to identify downsides for the scenario described. If something is a downside, then it should be quantifiable and it should clearly have a negative impact.

**Background:**

I'm working in a project for which we take a yaml file with some values and use those to render Jinja2 template files which result in Terraform configuration files. Conceptually is something like:

```
render('jinja2_template1.tf.j2', 'values.yaml') ==>> config1.tf
```

The resulting files contain Terraform code which define some infrastructure configuration.

In our code base there was a lot of boilerplate Terraform code and using templates to generate it was an improvement over having to maintain it by hand.

**Problem:** The question now is: do we keep the rendered Terraform source code files under version control or not?

Here are some pros/cons I am able to see and that make me lean in the direction of keeping them under version control, however I would like to see if others can identify downsides that I can't see now, then I can get a more balanced view of the trade-offs.

One note about the setup: our build process runs in a public cloud provider and we pay for consumption, so the more resources we use (storage, compute, network) the more expensive it gets. Same goes for time, slower/longer builds generate higher costs.

**Option 1: keep rendered source code files under version control:**

Pros:

1. generate only once
2. we can trace the evolution of the rendered file easily

Con:

1. not really necessary since the files can be generated anytime when required

**Option 2: stop tracking rendered source code files in version control**

Pros:

1. less source code in the repo

Cons:

1. we cannot easily track the evolution of the rendered files
2. longer debug times since we must generate the files before we can start debugging
3. unnecessarily generating the same files on every pipeline build
4. increased costs: if we're not careful we sometimes even generate the same files multiple times in the same build, e.g., one for linting, once to generate the TF plan, once to run TF apply, etc.
5. increased costs: if we're really dumb, we can end up generating up to 40k files -- instead of only 400 -- in one month, e.g. 100 commits per month, 4 stages in our pipeline, 100 different input yaml files: 100x4x100 = 40 k

**UPDATE #1: Re: Using an artifact repository or an SCM**

@Ewan made a point that I would like to address, he wrote:

> Source control is not a document management system or a general storage system. Your generated templates should be saved so that you can roll back deployments and stuff,

The scenario I describe in this question is one in which the output artifact is also source code, in this case, Terraform code. It is not just a document.

I could use an artifact repository to store the resulting Terraform source code and I could include the source code revision next to the artifact so that I can track the revision it came from.

At that point it's clear to me that I'm using such an artifact repository to do the job of a source control management system, namely keeping track of source code revisions, so it seems a better/simpler choice to just keep the generated/rendered source code in the repo as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see any 'cons' in leaving the generated code out of source control.     Why would you be tracking changes in the rendered files?    Why does it matter if the files are generated on every build?   Why does it matter if the same files are generated multiple times?   Why does it matter how many times the files are generated?     Assuming this is all a fully automated process that happens in the background, then why does it matter whether it's 40 times or 40,000 or even 40 billion times?

Comment: @BenCottrell usually generated code is needed for local development for completions, navigation and inspections in cases where the tooling can't generate them on the fly.  For example, using Protobuf will confuse some language servers, because it may be configured to generate binary code and not sources.

Comment: A more practical example - Eclipse EMF. It generates Java code. User either have to generate the code manually after the checkout, or keep a copy in VCS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Part of Your Project Should be in Source Code Control?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120477/what-part-of-your-project-should-be-in-source-code-control)

Comment: @Basilevs That sounds like something which can happen automatically - in projects which use any kind of suitable build system I'd expect to see it as a pre-build step so that the generated source is always available everywhere;   but even in projects which don't use a build system, any necessary pre-build or local setup steps can all be bundled into a shell script or makefile, then included in the readme.

Comment: how can this be closed as "opinion based" when we have that previous highly upvoted question on the same topic?

Comment: @BenCottrell our pipeline runs in a public cloud and every action adds up to the monthly bill. Unnecessarily generating/storing thousands of files has costs which can be avoided.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau not really but it helped me narrow down the question to: should we keep under version control auto-generated files that are themselves source code? I hope you agree that for this case the answer you have linked is not so clear cut.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't save the generated templates to source control. But I would save them.

Source control is not a document management system or a general storage system. Your generated templates should be saved so that you can roll back deployments and stuff, but storing in source control just so you can diff them seems like overkill.

When you run your template generation, presumably you have a build pipeline or machine that does this and is able to save the generated template as an artifact to be deployed or redeployed at a later date.

As long as you hold on to these artifacts then you have achieved your goals of being able to see how they change over time, test, use and reuse them. There's no need to use source control as a storage system.

---

Edit in response to updates:

It's hard to quantify the downside. What I and presumably others have experienced is the use of source control as an "easy" place to store things like configuration files, documents, or semi compiled results as a lazy partial solution to a problem. The result is multiple git repos with random orphaned or abandoned documents in.

Here you have a terraform configuration, if you didn't have source control you would still have to store it somewhere, you would still want to keep track of the changes, but you don't have the complexity of features being added to a codebase, you probably have a change a month or even longer, you don't need branches, merges, pull requests etc

What happens when you put this kind of thing in source control is the meaning of these things is unclear. Is every commit a new deployed version? what does a branch mean? are you going to use tags? Do you have another build pipeline which deploys the config from source control or does the build that creates the config also deploy? How do you resolve a conflict? Are you going to put each config in a repo, or use subfolders, or branches, or forks? What about different environments?

All these questions tend to be unanswered, you force push a new version to git because its easy and you have source control to hand and assume that it solves everything.

It's not that you can't use source control for this purpose, but its not designed for it. If you do, you have to define how, and *why*. Your only pro is that you can see the diff? it seems weak.

Comment: In a sense, this is also why we don't track binary outputs for our builds in version control either. They are an artifact created by a tool. Version control is useful for human generated stuff, because we want to know why another person made a change. The "why" of an artifact change is always "because the tool did it" which isn't very useful.

Comment: This is why it's called "source control". Were managing the source of these artifacts. Not what it produces.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect address the points made in this answer and comments. Please take another look, the gist is that in our case, the generated artifacts are source code as well, what better system is there to keep track of source code than a version control system?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla i've added an update but the format of the site doesn't really support this kind of edit and respond edit thing. Your Pros and Cons seem artificial, you need to look at source control vs filesystems/databases/build artifacts/s3 etc etc. not source control vs nothing